# easier to put into words than to put into practice

Tags: idioms, idiomatic-language, sentence-usage

Say Bob's being given the task of coming up with an innovative method for streamlining the company's logistics. He works all day and all night trying to get it done. Finally, he puts together a ten-page report and submits it to his superior.

However, his boss was unimpressed. Bob asks for reasons, and he simply replies, "***it's easier said than done.***" To expand on that, he told Bob that his work, albeit creative and well-written, lacks any practical utility and therefore it's not worth considering.

My question is: would it be acceptable if I change it to "***it's easier to put into words than to put into practice***"?

Thanks!

Comment: "he told Bob that his work, albeit creative and well-written, lacks any practical utility and therefore it's not worth considering" - it does not sound like "easier said than done" is appropriate to this situation, though.  "Easier said than done" means something like "it *does* have practical utility, but it is much harder to do than you make it sound."

Answer (score 4):

"it's easier said than done." is an idiomatic expression in English that means it is easier to say some thing than do it.

That said, I don't understand the point of trying to rewrite it.

Comment: As Lambie says; but if you did want to phrase it differently, your construction means exactly the same thing.

Comment: @RonaldSole I just **love** your dogs. I wish I could visit. :)

Comment: Down to four. Growing old. They and us. Cumprimentos!

Comment: But, as @stangdon says, it doesn't fit the given scenario.

Comment: @KateBunting I am not responding to the "scenario". I am answering the question for the idiom and it's "re-write". And that is correct.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks for your reply. I am rewriting this to avoid using the same idiom over and over again. If I understand English writing correctly, repetition is generally considered bad practice. That's why I am doing this. 

Just to make sure that I get you right, you are saying that there's nothing wrong with my construction; it just seems pointless and does not fit the given scenario. Is that right?

Comment: @Underwood Yes, two ways to say the same thing, one of them is a idiom.